# Multiple constructors typescript in Ionic: how to do it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am a newbie regarding Typescript and trying to grasp what I am doing wrong. When using just one constructor, everything works fine. When I add a second one, everything goes wrong. Along the way, I have learned that you can not have two constructors, so that part is clear and I know why it is failing.

The problem is that I don't know how I can get it to work, as I need both constructors as they are entirely different things.

So, I have this:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
    public items: Item[];

    constructor(private myService: myService) {
    // Doing something here
    }

    constructor(public modalController: ModalController) { }

         async showModal() {
            const modal = await this.modalController.create({
              component: ModalPopupPage,
              componentProps: {
                  // something here
              }
            });
            return await modal.present();
          }
```

So you can see that I have two different constructors with a different type. How can I combine? I tried the following, but that also fails:

```
constructor(private myService: myService, public modalController: ModalController)
```

What is the best way to tackle this?

The errors I am getting:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.page.ts:17:5 - error TS2392: Multiple constructor implementations are not allowed.

ERROR src/app/app.page.ts:59:15 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'public'.
```

Comment: "as I need both constructors as they are entirely different things." - in my opinion, constructors should not contain "heavy lifting" logic (like your `showModal` function). Instead you should use a factory function instead.

Comment: You say your 2nd try combining them "fails".  What does that mean?  You'll need to post the error you are getting.

Comment: I have edited my post by adding the errors I am getting...

Comment: do you want to be able to open the modal from outside of the component? is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: the constructor in angular is used just for Dependency Injection

Comment: So you need to relay on methods (different than the constructor)to achieve what you want

Comment: What I want to achieve is to get the modal to work in any component or just this component, that's fine. As long as it's usage does not break the whole app (which it does now).